# How do I change the text of a turtle after being assigned in Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How do I display the money text again after changing the variable?

### Code:

```
def mix():

    global money
    global moneyt
    global style
    fc.hideturtle()
    fluid.hideturtle()
    acid.hideturtle()
    acidcheck = False
    ffcheck = False 
    fluidcheck = False
    money += 5000
    moneyt.write("$" + str(money), font=style)
```

Comment: Quick tip: I would refrain from using global variables as they can overwrite local variables. This is bad programming practice

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job:

```
def mix():
    global money

    fc.hideturtle()
    fluid.hideturtle()
    acid.hideturtle()

    acidcheck = False
    ffcheck = False 
    fluidcheck = False

    money += 5000
    moneyt.clear()
    moneyt.write("$" + str(money), font=style)
```

As long as you haven't drawn anything else with the mouse `moneyt`, just `clear()` the mouse before you write anew.  (If you have drawn other things, use a dedicated mouse instead, or use `undo()` instead of `clear()`.)  You also didn't need two of your `global` statements as you were only retrieving the content of the variables, not changing them.